# Display dynamic html code as html non-escaped

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I am reading file from s3 in rails. I display the contents of a file in a div. I would like to display exactly what is in the file. The issue I am running into is if the file has html in it, I want it to display the code. For example:

```
<div>test</div>
```

should not be displayed as

```
# what I get when I try .html_safe
test
```

or

```
# what I am getting now
<div&gt;text</div>
```

My current code in my view is (slim.html):

```
.col-md-8#pr_parsed_text_wrapper
  pre.pre-scrollable.prettyprint.linenums
    -@file_preview.each_with_index do |l, index|
      span.text_line class="line#{index}" #{l + "\n"}
```

Other things I have tried:

- The `h` method.
- The `raw` method.
- The `html_safe` method.
- Using `=` and `==` instead of `#{}`.

Comment: Where are you calling `html_safe`? On just `l` or on `l + "\n"`?

Comment: I think the whole thing?

Comment: ... It may have been l +"\n".html_safe